# Export RDLC report to .pptx

Tags: c#, converters, powerpoint, rdlc, docx

Is there an easy way to export RDLC report to .pptx? For now I find only one way - export it to .docx, and then convert it to .pptx, but I did not find any information how to implement this conversion in code. Any ideas? I know about Aspose converters, but they are too expensive for me, maybe there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the easy way was not found. My solution was like that :

1. Create a template .pptx file.
2. Write some code to open that template
   file and replace template text/images using [Open XML Power
   Tools](https://powertools.codeplex.com/)

[This](http://www.dotnet-geek.co.uk/index.php/openxml-power-point-templates-processing/) article helped me a lot.

Comment: The link to the article is no longer valid as it seems. To you have an alternative link?

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion [Report Viewer and Report Writer](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/aspnetmvc/report-viewer) can be used to export RDLC to PPTX.

[Example code](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/147340/PPTXEX~1-984055873.ZIP)

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.